How to choose which browser to use when running TMS WEB Core projects in Delphi?
Years ago when I was using IntraWeb, you were able to choose which browser to open the project in every time you run the project which was great for testing.
But in TMS WEB Core, it just automatically opens in my default browser and so I need to manually go and open it in a different browser, but then I don't have debugging for that other browser.
Is there a way to choose which browser to use when running my project from the Delphi IDE?

You can change the Browser from the Project Options (Ctrl+Shift+F11):

You can choose between the following options:

Default
All
Chrome
Firefox
Edge
Opera
Firefox Developer Edition
Custom


You can also set it for all projects instead of just one specific project by going to your Tools > Options in the IDE's main menu:

